# Pyinstaller Dll load failure 64bit

Tags: python, dllimport, pyinstaller

I have a simple python script that requires 64 bit python and I am using 
pandas. It works fine running with python.

I am trying to package as a single .exe via pyinstaller. The packaging is successful but when i run the program I get

```
3, Nevada\PyInstaller-2.1\script\dist> .\script.exe
File "D:\Week 33, Nevada\PyInstaller-2.1\script\build\script\out00-PYZ.pyz\numpy.linalg",     line 50, in <module>
File "D:\Week 33, Nevada\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270,   in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
 DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I am guessing it is trying to load 32 bit DLLs but im not sure how to tell PyInstaller to do 64bit

Im running Python 2.7 64bit with pandas 64bit

Comment: oh I knew there was a reason I was still using 32 bit python ;P

Comment: yeah I would love to stay in 32 bit land but I am getting memory errors due to the fact that I am dealing with 1GB of data.